# set constraint min 0 and max infinity

Tags: php, mysql, constraints

In mySQL I would like to set a constraint to an int(11) type to have a minimum value of 0 and a maximum of infinity.

How can I do this ?

Something like

```
ALTER TABLE jake (
   CONSTRAINT jake_const CHECK (thefield BETWEEN 1 AND ? )
)
```

or , I dont know, like

```
ALTER TABLE jake (
   CONSTRAINT jake_const CHECK (thefield GREATEST 0 )
)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Integer cannot store infinity
2. Check does not work in mysql atall: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html , *The CHECK clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines.*

For this case you could make it unsigned. And that is all...

Comment: So, ` The unsigned range is 0 to 4294967295` , according to [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/numeric-type-overview.html) right?